# Submitting old PHP form via AJAX/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, contact-form

I’m not sure if this is possible but can ajax be added to an older normal php form, or does it need to be a new/re-built?

I have a form, with all the correct fields and an anti-spam all set up, but needs to be submitted via ajax/no page load..

[php form code here...](http://pastie.org/private/xivwqfbmjtz8319cgzlzmw)

I have no idea how complicated or if even possible, if not i’ll have to try and build a new one from scratch using a tutorial but none i’ve found seem to have anti spam.

Comment: Yes you can. The old form can still be used on browsers without JavaScript activated.

Comment: I think you need to split the code up. The form and AJAX in 1 file that posts to a PHP file with your PHP code in it.

Comment: Essentially submit the form, it appears at the bottom of a long page and current it submits all fine, but loads the page and thus jumpts right back to the top...

Answer (score 1):

here's a start...

```
$('#oldFormId').on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // stops the page from loading...
   // do the ajax thing here.. visit http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit this via AJAX. Here is the short version of the answer:

Rather than setting this: `action=''`, you need to post it to a Javascript form handler which submits the form in the background and returns a response. If you use `jQuery` this is easy, because you can use `$.ajax()` to submit the data. **Update:** @Reigel's answer shows where to start with that.

Check out the API for that: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So you'd change `action=''` and the response from the form, by checking for `XHR` using a method like this: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax ... that is the most important change to your PHP code. You need to return a `JSON` response or something that your client-side JavaScript can go off of to know what to do next.

Comment: Thank you, i’ll have a look and see if i can figure it out.

Comment: Something you will want to think about is `MVC` as a design pattern if you get into `AJAX` especially. This is the Model-View-Controller pattern. THAT would change your application profoundly, but it will be the way to go in the long run. Think about it for the future.